# how to auto update files to S3 bucket when made changes in EC2 instance?

Tags: magento, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a Magento running on EC2 Instance running along with S3 and Cloudfront. I want to know when ever i make changes in any file in EC2 instance which also have a copy in S3 bucket, how can I make it auto update or force update so it can reflect changes in front-end. I know about the Invalidations in Cloudfront. I don't have any idea about update from EC2 instance to S3 bucket.

For example, if I make changes to `style.css` in EC2 instance I want to get it updated or force update to S3 bucket and then I can add the file name in Invalidations in Cloudfront to appear in my front-end.

Comment: have you checked https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/php/post/Tx2W9JAA7RXVOXA/Syncing-Data-with-Amazon-S3

Comment: I know how to upload in s3 bucket using aws cli. i am looking for the solution which will help me to make any instant change or upload as soon i make any change or upload any file to my ec2 instance

Comment: With files like `style.css`, you will need something that does what rsync does by copying over only modified files, and the AWS cli is capable of doing that. It needs to be triggered by you for immediacy or by a cron job for automatic update. Skin folder type stuff needs to be treated like a standard Linux site-to-site mirror operation. For image files, you'd have to create an observer that would invoke the AWS CLI for the files being saved.